# Why don't email sent from case include a reply-to back to the case?

Tags: email, case, email2case

When Salesforce support sends me an email I can reply back to it and it appears in the case on their end (I assume--I've never seen there support system from their side).

I'm wondering why the emails I send from a case to a customer aren't similarly configured such that when the customer replies to it the message appears in the case's activity list.

In fact, the only reply-to information is my own email address.

What configuration option am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

When composing an email inside a case, from "From" field is a pick-list that includes your own email AND the email-to-case address (along with any other configured org-wide addresses).

When the customer replies to the email-to-case address, and the thread id is inside one-or-both the subject and body, the reply will be included in the "Emails" related list--not the activity history.

Thank you for that information, Jim Rae!